# Issues exporting powershell to CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

It has been many moons since I have last done this and I am having problems exporting some commands to CSV.  The biggest one that is getting me right now is

```
$ADGroupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -property * | Select Name -ExpandProperty Name | Sort
ForEach($Group in $ADGroupList) 
{
Write-Host "Group: "$Group.Name
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | Select Name -ExpandProperty Name | Sort
Write-Host ""
}
Export-Csv -path "c:\Temp\test675.csv"
```

Works fine with out trying to export but the second I try to export the command will run and either generate a blank file or no file at all.

I am able to run other commands with out a issue exporting them to csv.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim,

From what I can see you're not giving Export-Csv anything to write. Try this:

```
$ADGroupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -property * | Select Name -ExpandProperty Name | Sort
ForEach($Group in $ADGroupList) 
{
Write-Host "Group: "$Group.Name
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | 
  Select Name -ExpandProperty Name | 
  Sort                             |
  Export-Csv -path "c:\Temp\test675.csv"
Write-Host ""
}
```

I'd test this but I don't have access to ActiveDirectory.
Also the Write-Hosts you probably don't want in the .csv file as they won't play well with the format, headers & columns.

HTH